# Javascript Regex to select every non-alphanumeric character AND whitespace?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, tried using -

```
/[0-9a-z]+$/gi
/[^0-9a-z]+$/gi
```

neither worked. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The second one looks fine. Can you show us an example of how it's "not working"?

Comment: What do you mean by "neither worked"? 1. what where you trying to do? 2. what was the expected result ? 3. and most importantly: what happened instead?

Comment: try `/\W{0,}/g`, and try starting to accept some answers people give you.

Comment: I'm trying to find longest word in a string. A word qualifies as a group of letters and numbers, without any spaces in between. If I use ' ' instead of the regex, I get a fine solution. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evTZh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var sentence_split = arr.split(/[0-9a-z]+$/gi);
```

with

```
var sentence_split = arr.split(/[^0-9a-z]+/gi);
```

... if you prefer to go this way.

Explanation: the original regex was anchored (with `$`) to the end of the string, and splitted by words - and not symbols separating them.

Still, there's more than one way to do the things you do: I'd probably go just with:

```
var words = sentence.match(/(\w+)/g);
```

... capturing sequences of word-consisting symbols instead of splitting the phrase by something that separates them. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evTZh/1/) to play with.

**UPDATE:** And one last thing. I felt a bit... uneasy about wasting `sort` just to get `max` essentially. I don't know if you share these thoughts, still here's how I would update the searching code:

```
var longest;
words.forEach(function(e) {
  if (! longest || longest.length < e.length) {
    longest = e;
  }
});
```

*It's `forEach`, because I'm a bit lazy and imagine having a luxury of NOT working with IE8-; still, it's quite easy to rewrite this into a regular `for...` array-walking routine.*

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evTZh/3/).

Comment: Works! Thanks! Could you explain why?

Comment: BTW, it can be useful to `console.log` the array as well (as I did in my example to illustrate what would be captured).

Comment: I do use console.log regularly.. EDIT. Could you help me change the code to `for...`? I have no clue how to... Just a few hints would help.

Comment: @Namanyayg Check `forEach` [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) at MDN. It'll be helpful both for understanding its usage and possible ways of replacing it. )